# declaration and definition of constructor of class and print out private and public variables?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class

I am having hard time, I am learning classes in C++ now, here is problem I have, I have to declare and define constructor, i dont know what wrong i am doing i tried but could not get the result please help

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 class exercise
 {
 public:
      //declaration: constructor of class exercise
      int public_var;
      int get_private_var();
 private:
      int private_var;
  };

 //definition: constructor of class exercise
 int exercise::get_private_var()
 {
      return private_var;
 }

 int main()
 {
      exercise object(2,3);
      int pub_var = object.public_var;
      int pri_var = object.get_private_var();
      cout << pub_var <<' '<<pri_var<<endl;
      return 0;
 }
```

Comment: A constructor is almost like a normal member function, but it has to have the same name as the class, and doesn't have a return type.

Comment: `exercise( int a_public_var, int a_private_var );` this's a declaration. Try out a definition yourself ))

Answer (score 3):

A sample constructor would be:

```
class exercise
{
public:
  exercise(int,int);
  int public_var;
  int get_private_var();
private:
  int private_var;
};

//Constructor definition
exercise::exercise(int a, int b)
{
  public_var = a;
  private_var = b
}
//rest of member functions
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to declare a constructor you should

```
class exercise
 {  
   public:
     //declaration: constructor of class exercise
     exercise();
     int public_var;
     int get_private_var();
   private:
     int private_var;
```

};

In order to implement (usually in .cpp file)
you should:

```
exercise::exercise()
{  
   //your code here
}
```

good luck

Comment: maybe it would be better to `exercise::exercise() : /* your code here */ {}` ?

Answer (score 0):

`get_private_var` is not a constructor. It's function that is called when you do `object.get_private_var()` - it's just a typical member function.

The constructor is the function that gets called when you construct your object (makes sense, right?). In your case, it would be used when you do:

```
exercise object(2,3);
```

This line constructs an `exercise` object called `object` and passed the values `2` and `3` to its constructor. It looks like you want to assign those values to the `public_var` and `private_var` members.

First you need to declare your constructor:

```
class exercise
{
 public:
  exercise(int, int); //declaration: constructor of class exercise

  int public_var;
  int get_private_var();
 private:
  int private_var;
};
```

As you can see, the constructor is declared just like any other member function, except it does not have a return type. That makes sense since the return type is clearly the class itself. Here I have specified two arguments.

Now we need to define the constructor, similar to how you have defined `get_private_var`, but again with no return type:

```
exercise::exercise(int x, int y)
{
  public_var = x;
  private_var = y;
}
```

And then you're done. This constructor simply assigns the values that are passed to it to the public and private members.

However, there is a slightly better way of implementing this constructor, using a member initialization list:

```
exercise::exercise(int x, int y)
  : public_var(x), private_var(y)
{ }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you build a class with constructor

```
class a
{
public:
int pubvar;
a() //default constructor
{
pubvar =1;
privar =2;
}
a(int one, int two) //constructor with intializing
{
pubvar = one;
privar = two;
}
private:
int privar;
}
```

now default initialization is

```
a myclass;
```

and initialize with your variables is

```
a myclass(4,2);
```

hope that helps